# app crashes when it starts after defining onClick method of an Actionbar Icon

Tags: java, android, xml

I just started programming android apps a few days ago and now I have a problem when I want to build an app with multiple activities:

Basically I want to get to my settings activity by clicking on the icon i implemented in the Actionbar.

I set the onClick attribute of this icon to startSettings

```
public void startSettings(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

in my (menu) main.xml file ...

but when I do this, the app crashes when I want to start it.
the weird thing is, when I start the method with a normal button in my activity_main.xml file, it works fine ... So I think the problem is in the main.xml file. It says in this file that the method startSettings in 'MainActivity' has incorrect signature. and "Checks if the method specified in onClick XML attribute is declared in related activity"
But I don't know what that means  ...:/

Here is the error in my console

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.kevs272.testing, PID: 31225
              Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.ashok.nougatCM, fontPkg:com.ashok.nougatCM, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.ashok.nougatCM, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
              android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler startSettings in class com.example.kevs272.testing.MainActivity
                  at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:244)
                  at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:444)
                  at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479)
                  at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
                  at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
                  at com.example.kevs272.testing.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:23)
                  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:360)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:88)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:331)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1353)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1633)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:132)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and this is my (menu) main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">    
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="startSettings" />

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />

</menu>
```

Comment: Can you add crash log and your menu.xml?

Comment: are you _sure_ the method is in the class where it is supposed to be?

Comment: the method is in the MainActivity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recomend you to put the function in the on onMenuItemSelected of the activity like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        startSettings();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

and remove the view param

Comment: wow, thanks! I used onOptionsItemSelected because i could not override onMenuItemSelected, but now it works perfectly ... i really appreciate that you are helping beginners like me with these for you easy questions :)

Comment: you're welcome, but can you vote for my answer and check as resolved?

Comment: i need reputation, if you have no, excuse me for the disturbs and my writting i'm from argentina

Answer (score 0):

your app crash in onClick because as your log say : `Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler startSettings`.

you define your method as :

`startSettings(View view)`

when you define onClick in menu xml file you need to define your method as following :

`xxx(MenuItem item)`

you set wrong argument for your method, so your app will crash with method not found exception.

so you must define your method as following :

```
public void startSettings(MenuItem item) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

or you can use `onMenuItemSelected` as [@dpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662321/app-crashes-when-it-starts-after-defining-onclick-method-of-an-actionbar-icon/40662603#40662603) said and remove `onClick` property from xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has a small problem.
you hav to use Activity name before ".this". for exmaple :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
 StartActivity (i);
```

or you can wrate it shorter, like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
```